# How to dynamically style a Styled Component that stores all the css in an external file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to dynamically render a Styled Component. In the past, this was easy to do because all the style declarations would be done within the component itself. However, now I am trying to keep a separation of concerns. Therefore, I have stored the CSS in an external file. This works fine and does the job, however, now I am trying to dynamically color the font based on props. I am not sure how to do that and have been looking all over.

Here is my component that needs the dynamic font color.

```
<Styled.HeroHeadline as="h4">
  {parse(el.header)}
</Styled.HeroHeadline>
```

And here is the styles file that I am declaring the css:

```
export const HeroHeadline = styled(Heading)`
  p,
  div,
  span,
  h4,
  h3 {
    display: block;
    color: {dynamicProp}

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      font-size: var(--font-size-h1);
      letter-spacing: var(--letter-spacing-100);
      line-height: var(--line-height-h1);
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
`
```

Anyone have any input? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

I tried to add find a way to store the prop as a value in the external css file, but wasn't sure how to do so.

I also have searched to see if anyone asked this before but found nothing on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

See the [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) interface.

It's possible to do, for example:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "red"
```